# Why the compact-open topology of the dual group $G^*$ of a discrete group $G$ coincides with the topology inherited from the product ${\bf T}^G$?

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, topological-groups, profinite-groups

I have following question about a step (tagged in the image below) in the proof of Prop. 2.9.1(b) in Ribes' "Profinite Groups" (p. 60):

$G^*$ has the compact-open topology which is induced by the subbase consisting of $B(K,U) =\{f \in C(G, T) | f(K) \subset U\}$ and $G$ the discrete topology by assumption.

How can $G^*$ be embedded (in topological sense) in $\prod _G T$ so that it's compact-open topology coincides with subgroup topology induced by the product topo of $\prod _G T$?

Here the setting...

[image]

... AND the problem...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can $G^*$ be embedded (in topological sense) in $\prod _G T$ so that it's compact-open topology coincides with subgroup topology induced by the product topo of $\prod _G T$?

In the quoted book is used the natural embedding $G^*\to \bf {T}^G$, $f\mapsto (f(x))_{x\in G}$.

Comment: A few more words would serve to clarify to casual Readers that you are addressing the specific problem raised by the Question.

Comment: Yes, but my question is why this "embedding" is compatible with KO-topology in $G*$? ...so every preimage of an open set in the product is open...

Comment: @KarlPeter Because these topologies have a common subbase $\mathcal S$ of the form $\{B(\{x\}, U)\cap G^*: x\in G, f(x)\in U, U\mbox{ is open in }{\bf T}\}$. Indeed, clearly that $\mathcal S$ is induced by the embedding. On the other hand, since each compact $K\subset G$ is finite then $B(K,U)=\bigcap \{B(\{x\}, U): x\in K\}$.